# java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: java, mysql

When I run the code:

```
System.out.println(this.getDefaultValue().getValue());
```

The console prints:

> 2016-01-26 23:32:12

As you can see by the following image, the .getValue() method returns a java.sql.Timestamp object, which has a value as displayed by what the console printed.

[image]
Now, an issue arises when I attempt to run this code:

```
System.out.println(this.getDefaultValue().getValue().toString());
```

The following exception is then thrown;

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.sql.Timestamp
>       at com.crystalneth.mysqlapi.columns.time.SQLColumnTimeStamp.getDefaultString(SQLColumnTimeStamp.java:158)
>       at com.crystalneth.mysqlapi.columns.time.SQLColumnTimeStamp.format(SQLColumnTimeStamp.java:173)
>       at com.crystalneth.mysqlapi.SQLDatabase.dbFixColumn(SQLDatabase.java:708)
>       at com.crystalneth.mysqlapi.SQLInitialize.initializeDatabase(SQLInitialize.java:254)
>       at com.crystalneth.mysqlapi.SQLDatabase.openConnection(SQLDatabase.java:245)
>       at com.crystalneth.mysqlapi.Example.main(Example.java:66)

I can't figure out what the issue is, since printing the Timestamp by itself works fine, but the .toString() does not work. Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Your code looks correct. The error is probably coming somewhere else. See the stack trace. What is at line 158? The `println` statement?

Comment: I should also mention the getValue() is a generic method, but returns a Timestamp in this case (this is the only situation I've had a problem with this method).

Comment: @Kon System.out.println(this.getDefaultValue().getValue().toString()); is at line 158 (attempting to get the string value of the Timestamp)

Comment: If getValue() is a generic method that is supposed to return a String, but actually returns a Timestamp, that explains why you have that exception.

Comment: @JBNizet No, in this case .getValue() returns a timestamp, as you can see in the image of my actaul post^^^. That is what I want. And as you can also see, the Timestamp it returns is not null or anything, so I have no idea why the .toString method isn't working.

Comment: I didn't find an actual solution to this, but just removing the .toString() method and using the actual java.sql.Timestamp object in the String I needed works the same.

Comment: Can you share the method signatures for `getDefaultValue()` and `getValue()`?

Comment: @shmosel http://pastebin.com/w3sxvvuG There is the getDefaultValue() method, and the SQLDefaultValue class for the objects it returns (in that class is the .getValue() method). Sorry for the delayed reply.